# changing the title of standard tabbar icons

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uitabbaritem

Is that possible to change the title names for standard tabbar icons provided by apple. Say for standard download the icon is like a down arrow with a text download, when i try to change the title in the interface builder it is not getting reflected as expected. Instead the icon is changed to question mark

Comment: Question Mark seems like missing resource. Have you added it to your project? Did you try it with code, too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that you can.  You could always use the down arrow in this set of free icons.  Then you could use whatever title you wanted.  Just put the icon file in your Resources folder and select it in IB.

http://glyphish.com/